# jQuery: any way to append variable to img without it loading twice?

Tags: jquery, performance, hotlinking

I'm trying to tweak this [hotlink prevention method](http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/hotlinking-protection-and-watermarking-for-google-32/) by having the img urls get the appended ?i only when visited by a JavaScript-enabled browser as opposed to bots.

Using this in the `$(document).ready(function()` works:

```
var img= $("img.myimg");
img.attr("src", img.attr("src")+"?i");
```

However, it causes the img to load twice.

Is there any other way of appending the parameter for human visitors that won't cause the double load? And to clarify, I don't mean the image shows up twice on the page, but that the server gets hit twice as the url changes.

Comment: what's the img tag like?

Comment: <img class="dheimg" src="/location-of-file/name.jpg" [height/width/alt] />

Comment: Oops...should be   
<img class="myimg" src="/location-of-file/name.jpg" [height/width/alt] />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image not only be loaded once, and not be seen in its best version by bots, then you can only load it in JQuery, just the once. Then slitcanvas' answer applies:

```
<img class="myimg" notthesrc="whatever.jpg" />
```

In the JQuery:

```
var img= $("img.myimg");
img.attr("src", img.attr("notthesrc")+"?i");
```

This way the image is not loaded in HTML, and not by bots. It is only loaded by JQuery.

=========

If you want a version of the image to be found by Google image and other bots, and then a different (larger, better, with no copyright notice or watermark etc) then you can't escape having two images:

```
<img class="myimg" src="whatever" />
```

In the JQuery:

```
var img= $("img.myimg");
img.attr("src", img.attr("src")+"?i");
```

where "whatever" is the URL of that will return the bots version - e.g. a lowres image with watermarking, and "whatever?i" returns the good one.

In that case two images are loaded, the first one being for bots.

Comment: Also, you could continue to load the image twice, but have a low res version loading first and then the proper one when jquery kicks in. Which probably links in with your hotlinking protection anyway?

Comment: Well, as per the article I linked to, it's not so much a high-res/low res version, but having two different urls (for bots and humans) so an nginx config can then do specific actions based on the presence of the '?i' in the URL.

Comment: One of my comments disappeared. I meant to ask how does the jQuery find in your version find the img's actual src if the file location is not in the HTML? I'm putting this in a sitewide JavaScript file, so it needs to append it to all img tags of the myimg class, so putting the file location in the JS file would not be generic enough.

Comment: I've updated my answer to store the URL in an additional HTML attribute that wouldn't cause the image to be loaded but can be referenced.

Comment: slitcanvas is right, put in a different attribute, like presrc so that JQuery can reference the filename. I edit my answer to take account of this and of the 2 URLs for bots and people.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have :

```
<img class="dheimg" presrc="/location-of-file/name.jpg" src="" [height/width/alt] />
```

Without the src tag and then add it using javascript after the page has loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img= $("img.myimg");
    img.attr("src", img.attr("presrc")+"?i");
}
```

I've updated my answer to store the path in an additonal attribute that won't load the image by default.

Comment: Thanks. It gets rid of the double load, but the occasional person running without JavaScript won't see the images, right? Perhaps jQuery isn't my answer then. One person I spoke to suggested running Varnish and using `vcl_recv` to strip out the ?i when serving bots.

Comment: That's correct. In the end though it becomes a weighing exercise as to whether google image indexing causes more damage than the loss of custom from non-javascript enabled browsers. I think you're going to have trouble implementing something like this client side without javascript. Another alternative may be to use php/asp/asp.net or maybe even php/IIS to verify the requesting url?